# UIPickerView "didSelectRow" selection with button leading to url

Tags: ios, swift, url, uipickerview, nsurl

I have a picker set up and want to have the user make a selection then tap a button which leads to a url. This is what I have so far:-

```
class PickerViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    var pickerData: [String] = [String]()
    var pickerSites: [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.delegate = self

        pickerData = ["Google", "Facebook"]
        pickerSites = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.facebook.com"]
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        label.text = pickerSites[row]
    }

    siteBtn.addTarget(self, action: "didTapSite", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    @IBAction func sitesBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIApplication.shared().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I've connected the "siteBtn" to a button on the screen. The picker and text label were working fine until I added the code for the button. I'm not sure if I've put the button code in the correct place. I know that I need the button to connect with the picker "didSelectRow" and that the "pickerData" list needs to correlate to the "pickerSites" list but I'm stuck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this is the minimal setup you need. feel free to ask if anything is unclear:

```
// outlet to the pickerview
@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

// datasource
let pickerData = ["Google", "Facebook"]
let pickerSites = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.facebook.com"]

// pickerview datasource methods
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

// pickerview delegate method
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}

// ibaction for button tap
@IBAction func goToURLButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let selectedSite = pickerSites[picker.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: selectedSite)!)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much André! Didn't think I'd get such a quick response :) Works perfectly, much appreciated.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help :)